How to achieve Gemini Recycler View Effect that only shows the latest two components in RecyclerView?
I want my RecyclerView to display the latest message at the top of the visible screen, pushing the rest of the components up. Only the most recent component should be fully visible below it, similar to the Gemini style. If the latest component doesn't occupy the entire space, the remaining space should automatically adjust based on the component's height.
I'm having trouble scrolling up the RecyclerView components because the latest component doesn't fill the whole space, and I'm unable to dynamically adjust the space if the component doesn't fully occupy it. Gemini RV Example, Scrolled up
I am not sure how to deal with different type of viewholders and offset the bottom height accordingly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
